# $E(a)=0\Longrightarrow E(a^{n})=0$?

Tags: operator-algebras, expectation, von-neumann-algebras

Let $(M; \tau)$ be the hyperfinite $II_{1}$-Factor and consider a W${}^{\ast}$-subalgebra, $N$.

Is there a (trace-preserving) conditional expectation, $E:M\to N$?

Considering, now, a more general context for $M$, given a conditional expectation, $E$, and a(n) (positive) element $a$ with $E(a)=0$, does it hold that $E(a^{n})=0$ for all $n$ (equivalent: $E\upharpoonright C^{\ast}(a)=0$)? Does it hold that $E\upharpoonright \{a\}^{\prime\prime}=0$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For your first question: yes,  every W*-subalgebra of the hyperfinite II$_1$-factor is the range of a trace-preserving conditional expectation.

For your second question. If $a\geq0$, you can use that $E$ is positive:
 as $a^2\leq \|a\|\, a$,$$
E(a^2)\leq\|a\|\, E(a)=0;\ \ \ E(a^{n+1})\leq\|a\|\, E(a^n).
$$
If $E$ is normal, then it will be zero on $\{a\}''$.

For $a$ not positive, let $M=M_2 (\mathbb C) $, $E$ the projection onto the diagonal, and $$a=\begin{bmatrix} 0&1\\1&0\end{bmatrix}.$$
Then $E(a)=0$, $E(a^2)=1$.

Comment: Ah! I had forgotten about normality. Thanks! Takesaki seems to only show the case of semi-infinite; where can one find a proof for $II_{1}$?

Comment: as an aside: does positivity imply $E(b)\leq b$ for all positive $b$?

Comment: Lemma 3.6.2 in Sinclair-Smith. Although the proof for the semifinite case should apply to the finite case.

Comment: The condition $E(b)\leq b$ for positives almost never holds, because it forces the images of projections to stay below the projection. As a trivial example, the trace in $M_2(\mathbb C)$ can be seen as a conditional expectation onto the scalars. Then $E(e_{11})$ is the identity.